# angular 13 form validation dynamic input textbox show error on touch

Tags: angular, validation, angular13, formvalidation-plugin

angular 13 form validation dynamic input textbox validation

I'm adding input text boxes dynamically. But form validations are showing by default when I click add source button. How can I show error messages on touch instead of by default.

```
<form #nonTaxForm="ngForm">
        <div *ngFor="let income of incomes; let i=index">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [id]="getName('amount')" [name]="getName('amount')"
                    type="currency" [(ngModel)]="income.cashflowAmount" #amountCtrl="ngModel"  required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="(amountCtrl.invalid && amountCtrl.touched)">
                    Must be between $1
                </mat-error>
    
            </mat-form-field>
    
        </div>
    
        <button (click)=" addSource()">Add source</button>
    </form>

  public addSource() {
      this.incomes.push({
        id: Math.random(),
        financialSubtypeCode: null,
        cashflowAmount: null
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reactive form to handle this scenario. In reactive form you need to use FormArray. The sample is here https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-creating-dynamic-forms-using-formarray-angular